# force an uninterruptable bash script to run on login SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am making a text based RPG, and would like to run a bash script upon login of a certain user (The script will basically be lua  then once the file is done, logout) but I don't want the users to access the shell, and I want it to log out as soon as it finishes.

I am at loss as to how to make the script so ctrl+c will not stop it and give users shell access..

I've googled, but I must not be using the right phrase...

If anyone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

They will be logging in over SSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting the script as the default shell of the user:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/the_script theuser
```

The script will then be run in place of the default shell and the user will be logged out the moment the script ends.

You will need to add the script to [`/etc/shells`](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/etcshells.html) for it to be accepted as valid login shell.

***Disclaimer:** There may be other security implications to this approach, so do take this with a pinch of salt and look further into it before deploying on a production system. For example, you may want to run your script in [restricted mode](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/restricted-sh.html) if applicable.*

Comment: okay, thanks, That's what I was after, Security is not a big deal for now, It's not a production system, but I will look into more if it does go on a production system

Answer (score 0):

do they actually need to login or is it part of the game - if it's part of the game fake it.

Comment: to login to the actual server :)

Using SSH or Telnet - doesn't bother me, I just don't want them to be able to interrupt it and get shell access...

Comment: it does answer the question but with a caveat.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shortcut for keyboard interrupts to something other than the default via the following command:

```
stty intr yourkey
```

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>, map the function to `^C` (if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

As far as I know, you can't map any stty functions to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>.